# Change a column value based on an array or table of values in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

There is a table 'commissions' with the values 'processed', 'id' and 'ticketnumber'. I have about 9000 rows in which the column 'processed' needs to be change from t to f. I have an excel sheet with ticketnumber values. I want to take the excel sheet, put this into an array or temporary table, and loop through these values to change the processed to f of the rows with a matching ticketnumber. The IDs of those that need to change are not sequential, so I can't do it that way.

I have a table, tickettemp, in which I have put the ticketnumbers into. I have seen other problems on here that are similar but the solution is to join tables, which isn't what I want to do. Is there a way to loop through tickettemp, check the value of ticketnumber against the ticktnumber of commissions and, if matching, change the processed value of the ticketnumber in commissions?

Example of what I mean:

Table 1: commissions currently

| id | ticketnumber | processed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11THJ12 | t |
| 2 | 2FG56H1 | t |
| 3 | 1244567 | f |
| 4 | 145HHHT | t |

Table 2: tickettemp

| ticketnumber |
| --- |
| 11THJ12 |
| 145HHHT |

result for commissions:

| id | ticketnumber | processed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11THJ12 | f |
| 2 | 2FG56H1 | t |
| 3 | 1244567 | f |
| 4 | 145HHHT | f |

Comment: 1) Export the data in the Excel spreadsheet as CSV. 2) Create a staging table in Postgres to hold that data. 3) Use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and its `\copy` command to import the CSV into the table. 4) Use [Update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) to join against the staging table and update the `processed` value where `staging_tbl.ticketnumber = commission.ticketnumber`

Comment: "*the solution is to join tables, which isn't what I want to do*" - it is **exactly** what you want to do. You should `UPDATE commisions c SET … FROM tickettemp t WHERE c.ticketnumber = t.ticketnumber;`. Do not try to use loops, SQL is not an imperative language.

Comment: Alternatively, use an array: `UPDATE commisions SET … WHERE ticketnumber = ANY (ARRAY[…]);`

Comment: I was thinking that join was something like append, where it would add the tables together. Thank you for the responses!